Val_accuracy inst changing and sometimes it alternates between it complement (100% - val_acc)
I was assigned to implement a machine learning model based on a paper I've read.
This paper implements a multi-task learning model for attribute classification (labelled images are the model input, by labelled I mean attributes annotations, 40 for each image).
It is a multi-task learning model because there is a shared dense layer right after the model input layer and 40 attribute branches, each one of them with their own loss function (binary cross-entropy for all of them) and own sigmoid activation function (on the last layer, to predict if each one of the 40 attributes are or not at the image).
After a lot of hard work it finally started returning probabilities on all sigmoid function on all branches, but the probabilities only of val_accuracy were wrong: The val_loss and the loss (training loss) were getting smaller and smaller, and the acc (training accuracy) was also in a normal range of probabilities values, except for the val_accuracy which were always the same value or it complement.
For example (5 epochs just for example):
The Accuracy for one attribute prediction at one of the 40 branches:
5_o_Clock_Shadow_Accuracy
0   0.823665
1   0.891178
2   0.891178
3   0.891178

The loss for the same attribute:
    5_o_Clock_Shadow_loss
0   0.921046
1   0.701494
2   0.913597
3   0.765397
4   0.894950

The val_loss:
val_5_o_Clock_Shadow_loss
0   730232.750000
1   300412.500000
2   376215.843750
3   0.747685
4   1.607191

And finally the val_Accuracy:
val_5_o_Clock_Shadow_Accuracy
0   0.882382
1   0.117618
2   0.882382
3   0.882382
4   0.882382

My model:
def subnet(shared_layers_output, i):
    
    att_branch = Dense(512, name='dense_'+str(i)+'_1')(shared_layers_output)
    att_branch = ReLU()(att_branch)
    att_branch = BatchNormalization()(att_branch)
    att_branch = Dropout(0.5)(att_branch)

    att_branch = Dense(512, name='dense_'+str(i)+'_2')(att_branch)
    att_branch = ReLU()(att_branch)
    att_branch = BatchNormalization()(att_branch)
    att_branch = Dropout(0.5)(att_branch)

    branch_output = Dense(1, name=att_list[i], activation='sigmoid')(att_branch)

    return branch_output

def multi_task_model():

    #Input
    input_layer = Input(shape=(512,), name='input_layer')
    
    #Camada compartilhada (1 única)
    shared_x = Dense(512, name='shared_dense_layer')(input_layer)
    shared_x = ReLU()(shared_x)
    shared_x = BatchNormalization()(shared_x)
    shared_x = Dropout(0.5)(shared_x)

    branch_outputs = list()
    for i in range(40):
        branch_outputs.append(subnet(shared_x, i))

    model = Model(input_layer, branch_outputs, name='model')

    return model


Train and test input shape: (n_samples, 512)
Train and test labels input shape: (40, n_samples)
Learning rate: 1e-03

5_o_Clock_Shadow loss, val_loss, acc and val_acc over 5 epochs
    loss    val_loss    acc val_acc
0   0.422385    1.949578    0.864272    0.8873
1   0.354094    151.987991  0.888797    0.1127
2   0.354356    58.867992   0.888797    0.1127
3   0.352891    94.257980   0.888797    0.1127
4   0.353390    10.997763   0.888797    0.1127


Have you tried CNN (convolutional neural networks), in most cases CNN converges neatly with image data, i have worked on a similar project before with the following model Architecture :
# Building the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.15))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.20))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(Dense(43, activation='softmax'))

# Compilation of the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Model display
model.summary() 

I have a public notebook on Kaggle on it if you want to check it: https://www.kaggle.com/code/yacharki/traffic-signs-image-classification-97-cnn
It's also worth mentioning that preprocessing in very important.

I think you can checkout few points :

if you have splitted data from 'train_test_split' then consider random_state=42
draw graphs of loss and acc to check for overfitting and underfitting , i think that data is overfitted and may try restarting the kernel


I tried to split the data from 'train_test_split' and nothing changed. But, looking at the DataFrame of one of the branches i've got this val_loss and val_accuracy distribution over the epochs. Please, take a look at the final of the question

have you seen any sharp corners on the graph that may imply overfitting and underfittng

and most imp try seeing multi tasking models of others on kaggle a ref i found https://www.kaggle.com/code/mohammadrezabaqery/multi-task-learning

another one https://www.kaggle.com/code/danieldelro/multitask-gender-age-ethnicity-92-2-acc
